# Alternatives for Pow on windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, rack-pow

I love pow for mac (http://pow.cx) however I have a few co-workers that are on Windows, is there anything that they can use to have the power of pow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no. Your best bet is to just update the hostname file, but that's not anywhere near as elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's anything directly comparable available for Windows. In general, Windows just isn't as friendly to develop ruby applications on. That said, pow [seems to be documented very well](http://pow.cx/docs/), so there's probably enough information there to port it to work on WIndows.

Assuming your co-workers can't easily get a Mac or linux machine to develop on, another option might be to run Linux in a VM using something like VMware or VirtualBox.

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to get them to move to Linux. Thanks!